# Java String Index out of range for email project

Tags: java, substring, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm writing a code for a beginners coding class and am having trouble producing a substring for my email validation project. Not looking for regex, just very simple beginner level coding.

```
package email;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Input: An email address of your choosing
 * Output: If the email is valid, return, "Valid" If invalid, return "Invalid."
 * An input of "connoro@iastate.edu" would return valid because of all the requirements an address should have is present
 */

public class EMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Enter an email address: ");//input prompt
        String bad = "Email is invalid";//shows if email is invalid
        String good = "Email is valid";//shows if email is valid
        Scanner In = new Scanner(System.in);//Reads input from user
        String email = In.next();//read the input into a String variable using In as the Scanner
        int atIndex = email.indexOf('@');//shows location of '@' character
        int lastDotIndex = email.lastIndexOf('.');//shows location of the last'.' in email String
        int dotIndex = email.indexOf('.');//shows the location of the character of '.'
        String location = email.substring(atIndex, -1);

        if((atIndex == -1) ||(dotIndex == -1)){//If the input email does not have '@' or "." it is invalid
            System.out.println(bad);
        }
        else if(atIndex == 0){//if the character'@' is the first character
            System.out.println(bad);
        }
        else if(dotIndex == email.length()-1){//if the '.' is the last character the email is invalid
            System.out.println(bad);
        }
        else if(lastDotIndex < atIndex){//if the last "." is before the '@' symbol the email is invalid
            System.out.println(bad);
        }
        else if(email.lastIndexOf('.') < email.indexOf('.')){//if the first '.' is the last character the email is invalid
            System.out.println(bad);

        }
        else if((location.length()== -1)|| location.length() <= 0){//If there is no string between the '@' char & the last '.'
            System.out.println(bad);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(good);
            System.out.println(location);
            }  
    }

}
```

> Enter an email address: prabhu_iastate.edu
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1960)
>       at email.EMail.main(EMail.java:23)

If inputting an email address without an @ symbol I get an out of bounds exception when first naming my substring here, "String location = email.substring(atIndex, -1);" any way around this error?

Comment: Don't describe your exception, include the *exact* text of the entire stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If atIndex is negative it will throw (as akos.borads said).

This will always throw error : `String location = email.substring(atIndex, -1);`.

Maybe you wanted `String location = email.substring(atIndex+1, email.length());`.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Could you explain a bit more why the +1 and email.length()? when introducing location?

Comment: atIndex points at the index of at character, since you want to skip it you need to move one further position.

Then you take all charactes up to the last position which is at email.lenght() -1 but substring second argument is the first skipped character (not the last taken) so the first skipped is at position  (email.lenght() -1) + 1 = email.lenght()

Answer (score 0):

You must check if the email contains @ sign and don't allow to go further, because this means that the validation have failed already.

```
int atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
if (atIndex < 0) {
  System.out.println(bad);
  return;
}
```